# What can do to find and remove semi-duplicate rows in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates

Assume I have this matrix

```
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(rnorm(410),205,2)
x[8,] <- c(0.13152348, -0.05235148) #similar to x[5,] 
x[16,] <- c(1.21846582, 1.695452178) #similar to x[11,]
```

The values are very similar to the rows specified above, and in the context of the whole data, they are semi-duplicates. What could I do to find and remove them? My original data is an array that contains many such matrices, but the position of the semi duplicates is the same across all matrices.

I know of `agrep` but the function operates on vectors as far as I understand.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `dist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set a threshold, but you can just compute the distance between each row using `dist` and find the points that are sufficiently close together. Of course, Each point is near itself, so you need to ignore the diagonal of the distance matrix.

```
DM = as.matrix(dist(x))
diag(DM) = 1            ## ignore diagonal
which(DM < 0.025, arr.ind=TRUE)
    row col
8     8   5
5     5   8
16   16  11
11   11  16
48   48  20
20   20  48
168 168  71
91   91  73
73   73  91
71   71 168
```

This finds the "close" points that you created and a few others that got generated at random.

Comment: Thank you. I know of `dist`, it just didn't occur to me that I could use it for this. A simple and clever solution!